# Struts2 Dependency Injection

Tags: spring, spring-security, dependency-injection, struts2, struts2-spring-plugin

I am currently creating web application using Struts2 with Struts2-spring plugin.

here is a snippet of my applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" scope="singleton"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    </bean>
    <!-- Springs Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <!-- Create DAO Objects -->
    <bean id = "userDao" class = "org.hitplay.users.dao.UserDao" scope = "singleton">
        <property name ="sessionFactory" ref = "sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean id = "adminDao" class = "org.hitplay.admin.dao.AdminDao" scope = "singleton">
        <property name ="sessionFactory" ref = "sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="authenticateLoginService" class="org.hitplay.services.AuthenticateLoginService" scope="singleton">
        <property name="userDao" ref="userDao" />
        <property name="adminDao" ref="adminDao" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="accountAuthenticationManager" class="org.hitplay.authentication.manager.AccountAuthenticationManager" scope="singleton">
        <property name="authenticateLoginService" ref="authenticateLoginService" />
    </bean>
```

Here is my AccountAuthenticationManager class

```
@Transactional
public class AccountAuthenticationManager  implements AuthenticationManager {

 protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("service");

 // Our custom DAO layer
 private AuthenticateLoginService authenticateLoginService;

 public AuthenticateLoginService getAuthenticateLoginService() {
    return authenticateLoginService;
}

public void setAuthenticateLoginService(
        AuthenticateLoginService authenticateLoginService) {
    this.authenticateLoginService = authenticateLoginService;
}

public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) throws AuthenticationException {

  System.out.println(authenticateLoginService);
 //Some more codes here
}
```

As You can see on our mapping we are injecting the `authenticateLoginService` inside the `AccountAuthenticationManager` class. we've even provided setters and getters for  `authenticateLoginService` but as you can see when we run the
`authenticate(Authentication auth)` method the `authenticationLoginService` is returning null we have no idea why this is happening. please note that AccountAuthenticationManager   is not a Struts Action

we are currently using struts2-spring plugin and spring security.

Comment: i think we need to use <bean name="authenticateLoginService"................../>

Comment: how do you get the reference of AccountAuthenticationManager? do you get the instance of AccountAuthenticationManager through Spring Injection? or you just use "new" key to create one?
I cannot see any issue in your configuration file, and spring will warn you at startup time if it failed to lookup/inject a dependency. Since you did not mention any exception thrown from Spring, I would like to know how do you get the instance of AccountAuthenticationManager.

Comment: @spiritwalker I let spring AccountAuthenticationManager get created through spring injection itself. I using spring-security with this. but

Comment: are u facing the problem with only authenticateLoginService or with other objects also

Comment: only with authenticateLoginService

Comment: check by injecting other classes to AccountAuthenticationManager.Just for testing only

Comment: it is injecting other objects its even injecting the authenticateLoginService on startup but when we run the authenticate it becomes null

Comment: how you can say it is  injecting the authenticateLoginService on startup

Comment: because it is singleton scoped bean, spring will instantiate all singleton beans at startup time by default, unless you explicitly specify lazy injection.

Comment: @sambapenugonda because  I've added a system.out.println("MY MESSAGE HERE") on the setter of aunthenticateLoginService. and I can see that message on startup.

Comment: I reckon you add some debugging code into your AccountAuthenticationManager, like print this.hashCode(); in just make sure it is the same instance when "it is injecting other objects" and "it returns null"

Comment: @spiritwalker how do I specify lazy injection?

Comment: @user962206, yes, like I initially said, spring will raise complain if it failed to inject a dependency. So it is really less likely that there is anything wrong in the Spring config you posted. I'm bit concern when the authenticate() is invoked, is it the same instance as the one created by Spring.

Comment: @user962206 you can force Spring to lazy instantiate a singleton bean . http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lazy-init

Comment: @spiritwalker I am currently working with Security, I already tested what you have suggested, it turns out that they both different instances. they both different hashcode

Answer (score 3):

StackOverflow doesn't like to have a long comments list, So I will continue here.
Ok, so there are two different instances of `AccountAuthenticationManager` in your system. Let's say the one created by Spring at startup time is called `instanceA` and the unknown one called `instanceB`. If the `instanceB` is not created by Spring container, then there is no way that `instanceB` can resolve it's dependency(`AuthenticateLoginService`).
If you can debug into the system, you might want to look into the thread dump and figure out when and where the `instanceB` is created and created by whom?

Comment: how to look at the thread dump? and who created who? using eclipse

Comment: if you can debug into your system, when it stops at breakpoint you would see the thread trace in debug console. 
you need to figure out who(which class) created instanceB